# Tabify text inside Sony Titles & Text

Tags: vegas-pro

The editor won't respect the space that I insert with the TAB key, it does (unsurprisingly) with regular spaces (won't match the same space length between lines at all, however). Is there a way to make Vegas respect them? Perhaps by using some special character instead?

The workaround would be to make another text clip in parallel with this one, but I want to know if this can be achieved without doing that.

[image]